# Laravel 5.2 add a condition to login in standard Auth controller

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I'm using the standard controller class for login user

```
<?php 
...
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }


    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

There's a way by using this standard class to add a condition in Authentication?
In Laravel documentation is written that it is possible by using for example

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1])) {
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}
```

But I've to create a new Login method or it is possible update the axisting one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwrite the function getCredentials() in AuthController:

```
protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    return [
        $this->loginUsername() => $request->input($this->loginUsername()),
        'password' => $request->input('password'),
        'active' => true
    ];
}
```

Comment: Is this the best way to do this in Laravel?